# Sometimes Properties.load() skip lines

Tags: java, properties

Properties.load() skip the second line of InputStream in the following case. Is it a bug or normal behaviour of Java?

```
public class PropTest {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        propTest("Test1", "prop=cat,\\" + System.lineSeparator() + "dog");
        propTest("Test2", "prop=cat,\\  " + System.lineSeparator() + "dog");
    }
    public static void propTest(String name, String test) throws Exception {
        ByteArrayInputStream stream = new ByteArrayInputStream(test.getBytes());
        Properties properties = new Properties();
        properties.load(stream);
        System.out.println(properties.get("prop"));
    }
}
```

Running this code results the following:

**cat,dog**

**cat,**

Comment: In one version, you're escaping the new line character. In the other version, you're escaping a space.

Comment: I think, because of the "\\" it should continue to read the property from the next line.

Comment: You have a trailing space before the new line. So it doesn't continue reading.

Comment: Yup.  It is a **documented** feature.

Comment: @Matt Thank you, I have understood it.

Comment: @Stephen Thank you, I have understood it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to the [Properties file format](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E23095_01/Platform.93/ATGProgGuide/html/s0204propertiesfileformat01.html)

> A property value can span several lines if each line is terminated by a backslash (‘\’) character.

You have a trailing space in the second version. So the line isn't continued. Note the whitespace rules, which are a bit confusing.

> White space that appears between the property name and property value is ignored,

and

> White space at the beginning of the line is also ignored.

So that means white space at the end of the line isn't explicitly ignored.

Comment: @Kalman sure, but they kinda specify it in the file format. I don't know why they wouldn't allow whitespace at the end. Does the 'cat,' entry actually have a "cat, ".